# Node.js - How to organize environment variables

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, dotenv

In the [**dotenv** npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv), it says in the FAQ on:

> Should I have multiple `.env` files?
>
> No. We strongly recommend against having a *"main"* `.env` file and an *"environment"* `.env` file like `.env.test`. Your config should vary between deploys, and you should not be sharing values between environments.

I simply don't understand this. Let's say we have only one environment variable, `X`. `X` will have a different value in development and production. **What should I do in this case? How am I supposed to put the two values in one file? And how to tell `Node` which value to use?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says that you should have only 1 .env file, meaning 1 per deployment.

So for every new deployment, you can have different .env values. Dev, test, prod will have different values, but each will have only 1 file.

The way you provision that .env file for different stages depends on the tools and environment you use.

Comment: So for example: I should use the `.env` file while in development, and then after building the project, change the values in the `.env` file of the build?

Comment: Depends, for development usually you just download the .env file from somewhere, customise it and that's it. It is not version controlled. For production, there are tools which generate this file and inject it.